# Arduino Uno board works but Arduino Uno + Wifi is not being detected

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

When I connect my Arduino Uno board it instantly detects the board and shows it in the list. But when I connect my new Uno + Wifi board it doesn't detect it. I also manually selected Arduino Uno Wifi but it still gives me the message

`Error uploading check if the selected board is currently available`

How can I fix this?

This is the one that's not working:

[Arduino Uno + Wifi](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/UNO-WiFi-R3-ATmega328P-ESP8266-8Mb-memory-USB-TTL-CH340G-Compatible-for-Arduino-Uno-NodeMCU-WeMos/32739934767.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.WA5MYA)

While this one I got does work:

[Arduino Uno](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Arduino-UNO-R3-Official-Genuine-Chinese-Version/32824877267.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.dX8tcR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10343_10340_10341_10541_10562_10084_10083_10304_10307_10301_10177_10060_10155_10154_10539_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10594_10557_10596_10595_10142_10107,searchweb201603_14,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=38a8ce51-b63b-4aaf-9e1a-be69a7e114e1&algo_expid=4321f1cc-8e32-4caa-abad-e6d67a3cb87e-0&algo_pvid=4321f1cc-8e32-4caa-abad-e6d67a3cb87e&rmStoreLevelAB=0)

Comment: Is it a genuine Uno?

Comment: I editted my question to contain the exact products. The power source inputs are different I don't know if that could have anything to do with it?

Comment: Install the USB drivers (CH340G). It's a cheap Chinese clone.

Comment: and the DIP switch must be in USB to Atmega setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Arduino isn't showing up on my computer. What should I do?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/my-arduino-isnt-showing-up-on-my-computer-what-should-i-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a cheap Chinese clone. It uses the cheap CH340G USB chip instead of the proper ATMega16u2 that real Arduinos use.

Install the right drivers and it should start working.

Comment: Thank you this worked! But I just wonder, what's the downside of using the cheap clone?

Comment: They have a habit of dying easily. But they're cheap to replace.