# Serial Port Issues Elegoo Mac OX High Sierra

Tags: arduino-uno, upload

**Edit:**
Unfortunately the question that has been linked to my question does not answer my question. I have followed its instructions but it is a slightly different issue. Any help on my question would be hugely appreciated:

---

Apologies but I am very new and trying to learn how to use the Arduino. I bought a starter kit from Elegoo the included an Arduino Uno (I think it is a knock off and no the real thing?). I Have been trying to get the code to upload on to it and keep getting the following errors:

> *Sketch uses 2282 bytes (7%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes. Global variables use 212 bytes (10%) of dynamic memory,
>   leaving 1836 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
>   avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude:
>   stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00*

So I know that that my iMac is recognising the Arduino but I am still not able to upload any code to it. I have spent hours trying work around solutions I have found on the internet or Elegoo have sent me.

I have three questions. Firstly if I just buy a real Arduino from Arduino (I had not realised I was being sent an imitation) will this solve my problems?

Secondly, if not can anyone recommend a work around that I would be able to implement? I am reasonably computer literate but not to the level of diving into the Terminal and inputting lots of code!

Thirdly, I am really struggling being a beginner with the instructions given by Elegoo, they are very badly translated and confusing. Can anyone recommend a way to learn the basics and complete some basic projects for a beginner. I am happy to pay for the tutorials if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Arduino isn't showing up on my computer. What should I do?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/my-arduino-isnt-showing-up-on-my-computer-what-should-i-do)

Comment: "So i know that that my iMac is recognising the Arduino " => How?

Comment: Ah hi! I followed the instructions in the question that got linked to my question. By going to About this Mac and then looking at the Hardware and the USB port and i can see under Communication device it says all the device information and then: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)

Comment: And in the Arduino IDE, you have selected a programming port that looks like `/dev/tty[something]` ?

Comment: The Port i have selected is: /dev/cu.usbmodemFA131 (Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560)

Comment: The Programmer i have selected is: AVRISP mkII. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't know if i should have also said when i plug it in there is a constant green LED and a flashing yellow LED

Comment: I have also tried to fix the problem with this video that says it is for High Sierra. I get the same errors, although the yellow light does become constant while my Mac is trying to upload the code.